# How to train and predict using simple markov model (not "hidden markov model") in python?

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, scikit-learn, markov-models

I have a simple dataset that contains some columns and I need to predict using simple markov model in python. I cannot see any support under sklearn library.
 My dataset columns are : "url",  "ip",  "browser",  "request".

I have loaded the dataset into python pandas.

I need to train and predict the "url" state on the basis of "ip", "browser" and "request". How to create a simple markov model and train it and predict a state('url') on the basis of provided independent variables.

Please make the python code explanation simple.

Answer (score 0):

if u mean simple markov model from [this](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/heemod/vignettes/c_homogeneous.html), then there lot of simple markov models to choose from markov chain, hidden markov model, semi markov model and so on, because all this model is time homogeneous. I think u should determine which facts/outcome is random, is it cont. or discrete ? is there any latent/hidden variable ? That u should be able to fix best choice for your model

Comment: I need to implement K-Markov model